# rspec (expect syntax) - syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting '}'

Tags: ruby, rspec

Switching to the new expect() syntax.

getting

```
syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting '}' (SyntaxError)
```

for this:

```
expect(subject.crumbs.last.data).to eq {:foo => :bar }
```

How to fix this syntax error?

Answer (score 3):

Another ways to fix:

```
expect(subject.crumbs.last.data).to eq(foo: :bar)
```

(Ruby 1.9+)

Answer (score 2):

This code works (adding parentheses around the eq value) :

```
expect(subject.crumbs.last.data).to eq({:foo => :bar })
```

Comment: The reason for that is that the opening curly brace could also be interpreted as the start of a block. And after a method call, Ruby's parser defaults to that. You have to use the parenthesis to resolve the syntactic ambiguity and ensure that the hash is actually a method argument.